# .NET Core console application exits with error code -2147450743 (0x80008089)

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I tried to debug a simple Visual Studio 2017 (v15.7.4) generated .NET Core console application that prints one line ("Hello, World!"), and it exits with error code -2147450743 (0x80008089).

Below is the whole message I got.

```
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.1\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[12828] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450743 (0x80008089).
```

And in the terminal I see the message
`Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070057`.

But when I tried the `dotnet run` command within a *cmd* terminal, it ran correctly and printed "Hello, World!".

I have searched for the code and got that error code `0x80008089` is for `CoreClrInitFailure` in the [dotnet/core-setup Git repository](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/src/corehost/error_codes.h)

Below is my environment.

```
.NET Core SDK(global.json):
 Version:   2.1.301
 Commit:    59524873d6

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.301\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.1
  Commit:  6985b9f684

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

And below is the *.csproj* file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

As [Eric Erhardt said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222633/dotnet-core-console-app-exits-with-error-code-2147450743-0x80008089#comment89437222_51222633), with the COREHOST_TRACE environment variable set to 1, I tried both with `dotnet cli` which works well, and Visual Studio which does not. And both generate the exact same to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)), except for two lines. Below is the result from the `diff` command.

```
$ diff stderr-dotnetcli.txt stderr-vs.txt
3c3
< dotnet
---
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
52c52
< dotnet
---
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
1453c1453
< HostRID is win10-x64
---
> HostRID is win8-x64
3109,3116c3109
< Launch host: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe, app: C:\Users\user\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ConsoleApp1.dll, argc: 0, args:
< --- Begin breadcrumb write
< Number of breadcrumb files to write is 4
< Breadcrumb thread write callback...
< Breadcrumbs will be written using a background thread
< Hello World!
< Waiting for breadcrumb thread to exit...
< --- End breadcrumb write 1
\ No newline at end of file
---
> Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070057
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: Try setting the `COREHOST_TRACE` environment variable to `1`. It will print out a bunch of information to stderr, but it should give you more insight into what is going wrong.

Comment: @EricErhardt I just run it with COREHOST_TRACE environment variable, Is there any keyword i need to look for? I read the log, and it seems fine, except it prints `Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070057` line at the last.

Comment: I compared two stderr, one with dotnet cli, and one with visual studio, I can see that `HostRID` part is different, might this be the issue?